# Print a number from a list that contains more than one number in an index

Tags: python, list

From the following list:

```
listofnumbers2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,[8,9]]]
```

I want to get only the number `8`.

How do I do that?

I have tried `print listofnumbers2[3][1]` but it returns `[8,9]`.

Comment: Try `listofnumbers2[3][1][0]`

Answer (score 1):

Sublists are indexed the same way that lists are, so:

```
>>> listofnumbers2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,[8,9]]]
>>> listofnumbers2[3]         # Item 4 is a list
[7, [8, 9]]
>>> listofnumbers2[3][1]      # Item 2 of this list is another list
[8, 9]
>>> listofnumbers2[3][1][0]   # Item 1 of this list is just a number
8
```

This may be more clear if you instead set the items to a variable, then you can see that sublists work the same as regular lists:

```
>>> listofnumbers2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,[8,9]]]
>>> item = listofnumbers2[3]
>>> item
[7, [8, 9]]
>>> item = item[1]
>>> item
[8, 9]
>>> item = item[0]
>>> item
8
```

You can index into lists as far as you want on one line with multiple sets of square brackets, for example to index an item in a very deep list you can simply use lots of brackets:

```
>>> my_list = [[[[[[[[[[3]]]]]]]]]]
>>> my_list[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
3
```